# Jmeter json path extractor - How to Remove [ ] from extracted value

Tags: json, jmeter

From [json](/questions/tagged/json)

```
token_id="token_id":"82903430-f9b3-4f4b-9efa-ee1b991cb735"
```

I am extracting `token_id` using [json](/questions/tagged/json)path extractor `$..token_id`.

And then using the variable in next post request, but it's showing extra brackets in call

```
"token_id":["82903430-f9b3-4f4b-9efa-ee1b991cb735"]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I belive that it is caused by changes introduced in [jmeter](/questions/tagged/jmeter)Plugins version 1.3.0 where `JSONPath` extractor support of returning multiple matching values [was introduced](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Changelog/).

You can work it around using one of 3 below approaches:

1. You can change your `JSONPath` Expression to

   ```
   $..token_id[0]
   ```

   So you won't have to remove brackets and quotation marks manually
2. I believe you have something like:

   ```
   getToken=["82903430-f9b3-4f4b-9efa-ee1b991cb735"]
   getToken_1=82903430-f9b3-4f4b-9efa-ee1b991cb735
   getToken_matchNr=1
   ```

   So just using `${getToken_1}` should work like a charm
3. You can use [Beanshell PostProcessor](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) to remove brackets and quotation marks. Add it **after** the `JSONPath` Extractor and put the following code into `"Script"` area:

   ```
   String getToken = vars.get("getToken");
   getToken = getToken.replaceAll("\\[\"(.*?)\"\\]", "$1");
   vars.put("getToken",getToken);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In JSON, brackets means array of strings, numbers, booleans, objects and arrays.

"token_id" is interpreted like a string array. Example:

```
"token_id":["82903430-f9b3-4f4b-9efa-ee1b991cb735"]
```

Make sure to change "token_id" to string.

Comment: ${getToken} is giving ["82903430-f9b3-4f4b-9efa-ee1b991cb735"]   I want to remove extra brackets

Answer (score 0):

Use `getToken_1` as suggested by Dmitri T to remove extra brackets, because in [jmeter](/questions/tagged/jmeter)[regex](/questions/tagged/regex) uses array to store the [regex](/questions/tagged/regex)response.

`${getToken_1}` is the proper Regex to remove the `[]` brackets from above response.