# Jmeter JSON Extractor to get a token value inside a response body

Tags: json, regex, jmeter

all. This is the response I got back after a GET request:

```
{"id":30,
 "name":"ABC, Inc.",
 "clientRiskAssessment":{"clientId":30,
                         "generalScore":70,
                         "federalScore":45,
                         "internationalScore":20,
                         "updatedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
                      "url":"https://example.com/WebPortal/Config/Tax/index.html?IsFrame=true#/app/questionnaire-response/GeneralTaxClientQa/abd8d723-dc4a-e711-811b-00505683008b",
                         "formattedDate":"01/01/0001"}}
```

I can get the whole value of the "url" by using $..url in JSON Extractor - JSON Path Expressions in JMeter. Could anyone please give me a hint on how to get a tokens at the end of the url only and not the whole url value? This is the token I would like to extract at the end of the url: abd8d723-dc4a-e711-811b-00505683008b  Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps, you might use [Beanshell PostProcessor](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell).  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32423857/3832970) (Point 3), you will need `.replaceFirst(".*/", "")`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew replaceFirst method only replaces the first character. I was able to get the token after changing it to replaceAll

Comment: Well, you do not need `.replaceAll` since only one match is expected. Anyway, both will work.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it to have the most stable extraction in my opinion :

Add to your HTTP Request:

- A [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)
- A [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)

Like this:

[image]

Where JSON Extractor is like this:

[image]

And Regex Extractor is :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegexPostProcessor with the below configuration:

Regular Expression: url.*\/(.*?)"

Template: $1$

Match No: 1

This would always capture the token from the end of the url.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following Regular Expression Extractor configuration in order to get this [GUID-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) structure:

- Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `token`
- Regular Expression: `([a-f\d]{8}-[a-f\d]{4}-[a-f\d]{4}-[a-f\d]{4}-([a-f\d]){12})`
- Template: `$1$`

Demo:

[image: JMeter GUI Regex]

References:

- [Apache JMeter: Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)